# Issue of Adam over RMSProp

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I am fairly new to tensorflow and keras. So I started out by working on CNN for image classification on the CIFAR-10 dataset available on keras bundle.
I found a very helpful code online that seemed to help me through the process. After running the code I thought I'll try tuning it. So I changed the optimiser from RMSProp to Adam and had a tiny increase in validation accuracy. But when I tried predicting the images the model almost always gave a wrong prediction. On switching back to RMSProp the model started predicting fine.

Is there something I am not understanding regarding the problem and why I am not able to use Adam despite it giving a better accuracy?

Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/KerasCNN-CIFAR/keras-cnn-cifar10.ipynb

This is my reference and I changed the optimiser code to Adam from rmsprop and encountered the mentioned problem.

Comment: The Adam optimizer can behave strangely as gradients approach zero. Try a smaller learning rate or a learning rate schedule.

Comment: @PranavVempati Thanks! I added a decay of about 0.01 with lr = 0.01. Now my model works great!